# File Upload button not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, safari

I have the file upload field in my page.It working fine on chrome and firefox but in safari it is not working .

code :

```
  <label>
            <div>
                <img id="blah" src="../images/picture.png"/><br>
                <span style="color:#4291ce">Add Logo</span></div>
                <span style="display: none;">><input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" name="userfile"  id = "userfile" style="opacity: 0; cursor: pointer; -moz-opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0);"/></span>          
        </label>



function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what happens instead?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the same issue you will face with IE9-(due to security) , You have to make the input file as relative with opacity zero and font-size equal to the height of the absolute div.